# Java List get last duplicate Object

Tags: java, list, set, hashset

I have a list of Objects which is filled dynamically and I want to keep only the last duplicated Object. I tried the HashSet to remove duplicates but it's not doing big thing in my case.Can anyone help with this ?
My User Object shown below:

```
 public class User {
    public int id,score
    public String firstName, lastName;

     Getters and Setters ...

    }


class getLasDuplicate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> a = new ArrayList<User>();

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(1);
        u.setScore(2);
        u.setFirstName("Mike"); 
        u.setLastName("Jordon");  
        a.add(u);

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(1);
        u.setScore(3);
        u.setFirstName("Mike"); 
        u.setLastName("Jordon");  
        a.add(u);

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(1);
        u.setScore(4);
        u.setFirstName("Mike"); 
        u.setLastName("Jordon");  
        a.add(u);

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(2);
        u.setScore(3);
        u.setFirstName("kaos"); 
        u.setLastName("family");  
        a.add(u);

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(1);
        u.setScore(3);
        u.setFirstName("Mike"); 
        u.setLastName("Jordon");  
        a.add(u);

        User u = new User();
        u.setId(2);
        u.setScore(2);
        u.setFirstName("kaos"); 
        u.setLastName("family");  
        a.add(u);
      for(User us: a){
     System.out.println( "Name:"+us.getFirstName +" "+us.getLastName+", Score:"+us.getScore()+", Id:"+us.getId());
     }
}
```

In this case I want to **find by Id** the duplicated Objects and get only the last Object of duplicated ones in the List, so if I print the final List content I want to have something like this:

```
Name: Mike Jordon, Score: 3, Id: 1
Name: kaos family, Score: 2, Id: 2
```

Comment: `I tried the HashSet to remove duplicates but it's not doing big thing in my case.` -- What do you mean by this?  Did you make sure to @Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `User` class?

Comment: I tried but I didn't know really how to keep the last element in the list by overriding `equals()` and `hashcode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `List` is your input and you want to get last duplicates, you can try converting it to `Map` and change it back to `List` again as below:

```
Map<Integer, User> amap = new HashMap<Integer, User>(); 
for(User i: a){
    amap.put(i.getId(), i);  //when duplicate User with same Id is added, new User value will replace old one. 
                             //So Id will always be mapped to last User with that Id
}

List<User> newA = new ArrayList(amap.values());
```

Then printing `newA` should give you intended result.